# Accessing guest VirtualBox console via headless host SSH?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, console, host, headless

I've looked quite some time for this, and just can't find anything.

Is there a way to access a VirtualBox guest consolle, via headless host SSH session? I.e. without any RDP/VNC protocols, just like on Xen, via `xen console VMNAME`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can run SSH on the guest and since version 4, you can even forward ports across the NAT as well.

Comment: I would gladly do this, but for this I need to change the static IP on guest machine (which was imported from another host).

Comment: Unfortunately, no SSH into the hypervisor layer in lieu the vRDP functionality.

Comment: Thanks, eventually setting up RDP was much easier then thought, and it even punched through firewall via port 80: http://forums.overclockers.com.au/showthread.php?p=12723087

Comment: Glad that it worked out for you.